# USRP_UHD version installed with REDHAWK

Tags: redhawksdr, usrp

I installed REDHAWK 1.10.1 on CentOS 6.6, and as part of 1.10.1, there is a USRP_UHD device. It seems, as part of the REDHAWK install, the Ettus USRP_UHD driver (v3.5.3) is installed as well since I am able to run utilities such as uhd_usrp_probe. These utilities are located in /usr/bin, however, there should be some examples included with the driver as well.

I installed the USRP_UHD driver (v3.8.2) on my OS X laptop as a test, and I have the usual utilities (uhd_usrp_probe, etc.) and also I have examples such as benchmark_rate which is helpful is troubleshooting (http://www.ettusresearch.com/content/files/kb/application_note_uhd_examples.pdf). In OS X, these files are located in /opt/local/share/uhd/.

I can not find these examples in CentOS. Does REDHAWK not install them? How can I install them as they seem like they could be useful?

Comment: The USRP_UHD Device uses the Ettus uhd library to interface with the USRP hardware.  So unless you are planning on developing the USRP_UHD Device, you shouldn't need the documentation.  That being said, you can try yum install uhd-devel but I don't have a way to test that right now.  You can also download the source and install the docs from that

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was a bit unclear by referring to them as "examples" (that's what Ettus calls them). They're actually more along the lines of utilities--for example, the benchmark allows you to exercise the device at different sample rates, etc, and see if there are any underflows, overflows, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uhd package provided by the REDHAWK yum repo is modeled off of the Fedora spec file of the [uhd package](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/uhd.git).  They have chosen to remove the examples and tests folder from the built product prior to packaging it.  See line 84 and 85 from the uhd spec file shown here from the [Fedora 19 branch](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/uhd.git/tree/uhd.spec?h=f19).

This removal of the examples and tests directories goes back all the way to the initial check in of the spec file so it is unclear why this decision was made.

To get these binaries, you could build the uhd drivers from source.  See the [UHD build guide](http://files.ettus.com/manual/page_build_guide.html) for information on how to build the UHD driver from source.